# format the logs by an HTML template

Tags: python, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I'm retreiving the cloudwatch logs, putting then in the logger file, then send them by mail using Amazon SES. I want a way to format the fileHandler of the logger before sending it. I really want to have a nice readable email with colors and columns ...

```
logLevel = logging.INFO
logger1.setLevel(logLevel)
formatter = logging.Formatter(' :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s')
fileHandler = os.path.join('/tmp/', 'error-logs.log')
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileHandler, maxBytes=0, backupCount=0)
fh.setLevel(logLevel)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger1.addHandler(fh)
```

This is how I fill the logger:

```
output = []
output.append(event['message'])
logger1.info(' | '.join(output))
```

After filling the file with logger, I send the mail like this:

```
for file in sorted(glob.glob(filehandler + '*'), key=os.path.getmtime):
            body = open(file, 'r').read()
            subject = objet+" %s" % (today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
            for email in emailarg.split(','):
                response = ses.send_email(
                            Source = email,
                            Destination={
                                'ToAddresses': [
                                    email,
                                ],
                            },
                            Message={
                                'Subject': {
                                    'Data': subject
                                },
                                'Body': {
                                    'Text': {
                                        'Data': body
                                    },
                                }
                            }
                        )

            os.remove(file)
```

Do you have any way to nicely format the log file (text) using HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by :

- putting HTML tags in the output list (using table tags)
- Using HTML as the format of the Message for the body of AWS SES like this :

> ```
> response = ses.send_email(
>                           Source = email,
>                           Destination={
>                               'ToAddresses': [
>                                   email,
>                               ],
>                           },
>                           Message={
>                               'Subject': {
>                                   'Data': subject
>                               },
>                               'Body': {
>                                   'Html': {
>                                       'Data': body
>                                   },
>                               }
>                           }
>                       )
> ```